# Multiple actions in React reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have two actions to handle the states in my reducer

```
INCREMENT_LIKES

VISUALIZE_WIDTH
```

Those actions work perfectly individually but since i want to pair them, something goes wrong

**Console error**

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of undefined*

[image: Console]
[image: Debugger]

The Action

```
// increment
export function visualize(index) {
  return {
    type: 'VISUALIZE_WIDTH',
    index
  }
}

export function increment(index) {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT_LIKES',
    index
  }
}
```

The reducer

```
export default function svgs(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_LIKES' :
      const i = action.index;
      return [
        ...state.slice(0,i), // before the one we are updating
        {...state[i], likes: state[i].likes + 1},
        ...state.slice(i + 1), // after the one we are updating
      ];
    case 'VISUALIZE_WIDTH':
      console.log("Incrementing dats!!");
      return [
        ...state.slice(0,i), // before the one we are updating
        {...state[i], w: state[i].w + 100},
        ...state.slice(i + 100), // after the one we are updating
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return state;
}
```

in my component

```
    <button onClick={this.props.increment.bind(null, i)} className="likes">&hearts; {svg.likes}</button>
    <button onClick={this.props.visualize.bind(null, i)}>Change Data</button>
```

What am i doing wrong with the actions?

Comment: Maybe you initialize them wrong? What is the initial state of svgs?

Comment: Did you check what value you have in state[i]? try verifying if state[i].w is null.

Comment: yes i = undefined while i debug, see the image in the question

Comment: Not sure the issue is in your actions or your reducers. Is it possible that state is not being passed down from the component object? Have you tried removing "null" from the bind statement?

Comment: very silly mistake i have fixed it, i answer myself now